# Django TruncHour without other date fields

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a series of timestamps from crawled Posts. Now I want to show a statistic where the activity of an author of the posts will be shown.

For this I want to filter the times of the posts (Models Posts contains the datetime field 'timestamps') in days and hours. The filtering for the days works. I want to show at which times (11:00, 09:00 etc.) the posts were created.

I wanted to filter the dataset like

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncHour
from django.db.models import Count
from .models import Posts

posts = Posts.objects.all()
hours = posts.annotate(hour=TruncHour('timestamp')).values('hour').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

but with this filter I receive a bunch of hours which contains different days, month, years... I only want to receive the pure hour without other parameters.

Is there a way to go? Any clue is welcome...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to obtain the hour, you use [**`ExtractHour`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractHour), not [**`TruncateHour`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc) which *truncates* up to the hour.

You thus can use the expression:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractHour

posts = Posts.objects.annotate(
    hour=ExtractHour('timestamp')
).values('hour').annotate(
    count=Count('id')
).order_by('hour')
```

Note that if there is no `timestamp` with that hour, then of course there will be no record in the result with that hour. The count is thus *not* zero, the row will simply not exist.

The `.order_by` is used to force Django to `GROUP BY` and thus "fold" the values with the same hour.

Django will generate a query for this that looks like:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CONVERT_TZ(post.timestamp, 'UTC', 'UTC')) AS hour,
       COUNT(post.id) AS count
FROM post
GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CONVERT_TZ(post.timestamp, 'UTC', 'UTC'))
ORDER BY hour ASC
```